# How to embed figure short descriptions (as would be displayed in the List of Figures) within the table of contents in LaTeX?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

The document I'm writing has all the figures in Appendix A (since there is a lot of source code included in latter appendixes, it would not make sense to put the figures as the final part of the document). I am aware I can have a separate list of figures that lists the caption short descriptions, but what I want is for this to be included in the table of contents itself. For example, instead of:

```
Table of Contents
1 Section 1 ......... 1
  1.1 subsection .... 1
A Figures ........... 3
B Source Code ....... 5
  B.1 more code ..... 6

List of Figures
Desc. 1 ............. 3
Desc. 2 ............. 4
```

I want:

```
Table of Contents
1 Section 1 ......... 1
  1.1 subsection .... 1
A Figures ........... 3
  Desc. 1 ........... 3
  Desc. 2 ........... 4
B Source Code ....... 5
  B.1 more code ..... 6
```

I've been scouring the internet but can only find information on how to include the List of Figures' page number in the table of contents using `\addcontentsline{toc}`. Would I manually have to include caption short descriptions with `\addcontentsline{toc}` for every figure or is there some way I can automate this?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution redefining `\ext@figure` to `toc`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ext@figure{toc}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test Section}

\appendix

\section{Figures}
\begin{figure}[!ht]\caption{Description 1}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]\caption{Description 2}\end{figure}
\section{Souce Codes}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I only used the `[!ht]` modifier for the example's sake; I don't suggest its mandatory use.

Comment: The `\makeatletter` segment worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write into your document after `\appendix`, e.g.:

```
[...]
\appendix
\makeatletter
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
[...]
```